# refresh single select box on click with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, select

I've a select populated by a php query, that loads the nicknames of the users logged in a specific div, called “UserList”.

```
<div id=”UserList” name=”UserList”>
</div>
```

This select is placed in a php page, “userlist.php”, loaded by jquery. The php query works fine, so I've avoided writing here the db connection.

```
<select name="User" id=”User”>
<?  
$MySql = "SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Loc = '$Loc' ORDER BY Name";
$Result = mysql_query($MySql);
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$rs['Name'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($rs['Name']).'</option>';
}
$rs->close;
mysql_free_result($Result); ?>
</select>
```

My problem is that I need to reload only the select and refreshing it when a user clicks the select itself, so new users that enter the page are added by the php query and those that changed page are removed from the list. But whit every event that I tried the jquery loops, instead of activating the reload only once every time a user clicks the form and the first click event not even reload properly the php query.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#UserList").load('userlist.php');

$("#UserList").click(function() {
    $("#UserList").load('userlist.php');
    evt.preventDefault();
});

});
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AJAX to do this. AJAX allows you to query the web-server with out refreshing the entire page. [This example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)
seems like almost exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Put this inside your template:

```
    <div id=”UserList” name=”UserList”>
        <select name="User" id=”User”>
           <?  
               $MySql = "SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Loc = '$Loc' ORDER BY Name";
               $Result = mysql_query($MySql);
                  while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) 
                  {
                      echo '<option value="'.$rs['Name'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($rs['Name']).'</option>';
                  }
               $rs->close;
               mysql_free_result($Result); 
            ?>
         </select>    
    </div>
```

Then Change the Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#User").click(function() {
              $("#User").load('userlist.php');
          });

      });
</script>
```

And finally change the userlist.php file:

```
<?  
$MySql = "SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Loc = '$Loc' ORDER BY Name";
$Result = mysql_query($MySql);
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$rs['Name'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($rs['Name']).'</option>';
}
$rs->close;
mysql_free_result($Result); ?>
```

Comment: I've tried, but the problems is the same, it doesm't populate properly the select and it loops when clicked.

Comment: I tried but in this way the event seems to be triggered only one time (the first click after the page is loaded) and still, only the second click shows the updated options of the select field.

Comment: It still don't work, unfortunatly, now it seems to not properly send the php query to the db.

Comment: The db query is the same. However I noticed you used ” instead " in your html markup. You should definately change that. I just tried this with randomly generated user names, it works.

Comment: have you replaced your (wrong) quotation marks (”) in the html with the right ones (") ?